Getting google maps api key from process env
I need to add google maps api key into my .env file.
I configured my webpack according to this config and use it in my map component.
When I console log this key I can see it in console, But while using it with map, map opened just a second then I got a warning screen.
Webpack file:
plugins: [
    new Dotenv({ systemvars: true }),
],

Map component:
const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,  
    libraries: [GOOGLE_MAP_PLACES_LIBRARY],
});


.env file:
REACT_APP_API_KEY : "someKey"

Error that i got after a second

I just added this into my webpack:
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

For plugins:
   plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "process.env": {
                    REACT_APP_API_KEY: JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed.REACT_APP_API_KEY),
                },
            }),]

And just used it in my component:
googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,

